# Load data to a list collection from isolated storage fails

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I have stored nearly 150 high resolution images into isolated storage with 789x 1299 resolution. MY problem is when I load 60 - 70 images into the list collection it works fine but when it more than 70 Out of memory exception occurs in the bi.SetSource(ms). I am using the virtualizing satck panel in the item template. Whats the reason

```
        List<SampleData> data = new List<SampleData>();
        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 150; i++)
            {

                byte[] data2;

                using (IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {

                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = isf.OpenFile("IMAGES" + i + ".jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        data2 = new byte[isfs.Length];
                        isfs.Read(data2, 0, data2.Length);
                        isfs.Close();
                    }

                }


                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data2);

                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

                bi.SetSource(ms);

                data.Add(new SampleData() { Name = bi });



            }
            this.list.ItemsSource = data;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

        }



        }



    public class SampleData
    {
        public ImageSource Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


    }
}
```

}

```
      <ListBox x:Name="list" Width="480">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="10">

                        <Image Height="500" Width="500" Source="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" Orientation="Vertical"/>

                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe by creating the `BitmapImages` first, WP7 is allocating the memory for each image up front, rather than when the item in the listbox scrolls into view. Try storing the byte array, rather than the `BitmapImage`, in the `SampleData` class, and then create the `BitmapImage` when called, via a property.

So SampleData would look something like this:

```
public class SampleData
{
    public byte[] ImgData {get;set;}
    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get
        {
            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ImgData);
            bi.SetSource(ms);
            return bi;
        }
    }
}
```

Being that you have many high resolution images, you may still run into performance issues - I might suggest storing lower resolution versions of those images for the `ListBox`, and then displaying the high resolution image when the user needs to view that particular image? Hope this helps!